# Query of two table with different structure

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that shows Cities and County Table that shows counties, but the structure of tables is different so I cannot use Union. I need to show all recorded from both table that has a name for example 'Orange',

These are my 2 queries that I want in combine.

```
select * from [geo].[tblCounty] co
where co.CountyName like 'ORANGE%'

 select * from [geo].[tblCity] c
 where  c.CityName like 'ORANGE%'
```

Table County:

[image]

City Table:

[image]

I need all county or citys that has Orange on the CountyName or CityName. basically 3 row of record with these data.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the same type columns instead of *

```
select co.CountyName  from [geo].[tblCounty] co
where co.CountyName like 'ORANGE%'
union
 select  c.CityName  from [geo].[tblCity] c
 where  c.CityName like 'ORANGE%'
```